# Select all the elements that have a particular id AND class

Tags: javascript, jquery

**(UPDATED)**. The context is the function below I am trying to get working. Am currently messing around in the console to see what's up, the first variable `selectChoices` is logging an empty `NodeList`. Can't seem to select all the elements that have an id of `translateBoxCover` and a class of `choices`.

```
function correctChoices() {
    var selectChoices = document.querySelectorAll('#translateBoxCover .choices');
    var checkChoicesArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < selectChoices.length; i++) {
        checkChoicesArray.push(selectChoices[i].textContent);
        console.log(checkChoicesArray);
    }
    if (checkChoicesArray.join('') == '我很很很喜欢中国') {
        return true;
    }
}
```

(Updated). I have included some more context: a javascript function that removes .choices to and fro the #translateBoxCover. When a .choices is clicked it is added to the div with the id #translateBoxCover. The function correctChoices will fire when the submit button is clicked (not included) to see if the .choices text content are in the right order. Below that is the html file in question. It seems everyone agrees that I have wrongly used an id when I should be using a class?

```
$('.choices').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.parent().attr('id') == 'translateBoxCover') {
    var index = $this.data('index');
    if (index == 0) {
      $this.prependTo($("#choicesWrapper"));
    } else {
      $this.insertAfter($("#choicesWrapper .choices").eq(index-1));
    }
  } else {
    $this.data('index', $this.index());
    $this.appendTo("#translateBoxCover");
  }
});
    <div id = 'translateBoxWrapper'>
        <div id = 'translateBox'>
            <div id = 'translateBoxCover'></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id = 'choices'>
        <div id = 'choicesWrapper'>
            <div class = 'choices'>很</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>中国</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>美国</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>爱</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>喜欢</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>我</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>很</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>很</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>他</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>川普</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>厕所</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>想</div>
            <div class = 'choices'>你</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique.  If they are, then the class part is redundant.

Comment: each element have class+id both at the same time? id need to be unique

Comment: Only 1 element may have a specific ID. Meaning, you can only have one `#translateBoxCover` in the DOM.

Comment: with jquery $('#translateBoxCover.choices') will do it

Comment: There will always be one item that has a particular id and class. But you got the selector wrong, what you wanted is `#translateBoxCover.choices`

Comment: hope my updates provide more context for what I need to do. Perhaps querySelectorAll is the wrong way to go about it? Maybe select all the children of the element #translateBoxCover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ids and classes in a selector like `#id.class`.

```js
var el = document.querySelector( '#my_id.my_class' );
console.log( el );
```

```html
<div class="my_class"></div>
<div class="my_class"></div>
<div id="my_id" class="my_class"> </div>
```

It's worth noting, as has already been pointed out, that `id`s should be unique and therefore if you're using an id as a selector, you shouldn't also need a class as it is redundant.

```js
var el = document.querySelector( '#my_id' );
console.log( el );
```

```html
<div class="my_class"></div>
<div class="my_class"></div>
<div id="my_id" class="my_class"></div>
<div id="another_id" class="my_class"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can and the selectors by concatenating both id and class name.

```
var selectChoices = document.querySelectorAll('#translateBoxCover.choices');
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I misread what was being looked for. The following is true if you want a particular element by ID and more by class.

```
var selectChoices = document.querySelectorAll('#translateBoxCover .choices')
```

should read (note the comma between #translateBoxCover and .choices):

```
var selectChoices = document.querySelectorAll('#translateBoxCover, .choices')
```

Comment: This does an OR, not an AND. You need to concatenate the two selectors instead.

Comment: The comma is tge same as an OR, but he needs an AND.